# Does IE11 Edge Document mode support ES6?

Tags: internet-explorer, ecmascript-6

So I know a lot of ES6 JS methods are NOT supported in IE11...however if the document mode is set to Edge (Which DOES support ES6) will it actually work within IE11?

(I don't have a Windows 10 computer nearby) But I had wondered if it's possible to impart Edge "compatibilities" in the actual IE11 browser?

I know "User-Agent" even being in Chrome/Firefox (Which support ES6) doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The document mode "Edge" means "The highest mode available". It puts IE 11 into IE 11 mode, IE 10 into IE 10 mode and so on.

It is unrelated to the browser named "Edge".

IE does not appear to be under active development. It appears to only get security fixes, not new features. New features are added to the browser named Edge instead.